# Low Search: Remember previous search

Tags: low-search

**Scenario:**

WHEN User searches for a random term lets say `pepe` on my initial search page.

THEN User sees the results page with lots of results.

THEN User wants to filter those results by Clicking in any of the Categories filter

THEN User sees the results of `pepe` for the specific category that he selected.

**Problem**

I'm able to do the first search and display all results independent of category. When I try to run a 2nd search on the result's page and pass the filter `category` I don't know how to make the system remember the first query or pass the value of `search:title`.

How can I achieve that?

**Initial Search Page**

```
{exp:low_search:form
  form_attribute="search-form"
  result_page="search"
  collection="article"
  search_mode="all"
}
  <fieldset>
    <label for="keywords">Search</label>
    <input type="search" name="search:title"/>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </fieldset>
{/exp:low_search:form}
```

**Results Page (UPDATED WITH WORKING CODE)**

```
    <!-- Category filter-->


     {exp:low_search:form
            form_attribute="search-form"
            result_page="search"
            collection="article"
            search_mode="all"
            remember="search:title"
            query="{segment_2}"
}

<fieldset>
    {exp:channel:categories parent_only="yes" style="linear"}
        <button  name="category" value="{category_id}">{category_name}</button>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</fieldset>

{/exp:low_search:form}

<!-- Search Results-->
{exp:low_search:results
    limit="10"
    query="{segment_2}"
    collection="article|food"
    status="open"
}
  {if count ==  1}<ol>{/if}
    <li><a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{title}</a></li>
  {if count == total_results}</ol>{/if}
  {if no_results}No search results{/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`remember=""` parameter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag-parameters) on the second Form tag.

> Set to the names of the parameters you want to pass through to the next search without having input fields for them in the form.

So, instead of having the hidden input field in the second form, use `remember="search:title"`.

---

Additionally, there's a couple of things you can improve:

- Instead of using `search:title` (the [Field Search filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search)), try using `keywords` (the [Keywords filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#keywords)). This will increase performance and is the preferred filter for free text searches.
- Don't add any filter parameters (like `collection` and `search_mode`) to your Form tag; they have no effect there. Add them to the Results tag instead. Also `search_mode` has been superseded by `keywords:mode` in Low Search v4.

Comment: I've added the `remember="search:title"` to the tag and amended my code sample on the main post, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Make sure the `query=""` param is set, too.